# Keep URL params ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a web app with an entrance point in a different app.
So by the time user gets to my app they have some parameters in the url like so:

`http://myapp.com/#/new?param1=value&param2=value2`

In my app I have 3-4 tabs each of which is it's own state and is accessed with `ui-sref="state"`

The issue is that when I switch to any of these states I lose the parameters that user came in with initially.

In a nutshell all I want `http://myapp.com/#/differentstate?param1=value&param2=value2` instead of `http://myapp.com/#/differentstate` when I switch states.

I am not sure how to set that up...
Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inside of your angular app's `.run()` function you can do this:  (you will need to DI `$rootScope`, and `$location`)

```
    var locationSearch;

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        //save location.search so we can add it back after transition is done
        locationSearch = $location.search();
    });

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        //restore all query string parameters back to $location.search
        $location.search(locationSearch);
    });
```

Comment: This is not a good solution as it would cause your toState Controller to be invoked twice due to the $location.search(locationSearch) in the $stateChangeSuccess

Comment: @MilenKovachev: only if you change your state in the `$stateChangeSuccess`. `$location.search(locationSearch)` doesn't do that.

Comment: I do not change my state in the $stateChangeSuccess, I think it has to do with the reloadOnSearch parameter, which by default is true on every route definition

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about that. True.

Comment: Love this solution, but this does not work when you "Open Link in New Tab"

Comment: @Mystec that is because the href on the anchor tag doesn't have the query string in it. You would have to append it yourself manually or override/extend ui-sref to append it. This is on the link/anchor tag itself.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $location.search only works while you remain in the same window. To anchor all links, you have to manually extend ui-sref to include the url parameters. Now, your links can be "Open in new Tab" and preserve the parameters. This code also includes a kludge to convert ~2F and %2F to / so your links stay consistent. To do this:

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $location ) {
  // Url parameters
  var locationSearch = $location.search();
  // Set param1 
  $rootScope.site = {};
  $rootScope.site.param1 = _url_decode_slash(locationSearch.param1);


  // Hack to decode URL params with Slash (/)
  function _url_decode_slash (param) {
      if (!param) return param;
      param = param.replace(/~2F/g, "/"); // Replace all '~2F' to /
      param = param.replace(/%2F/g, "/"); // Replace all '%2F' to /
      return param;
  }
}
```

Then in your index.html

```
<a ui-sref="request.add( {param1: site.param1 } )" >
```